# Removing redundant CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make my own TreeView based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp) awesome link from w3.com, I wanted to add animation to my TreeView's arrow and added some extra code to my CSS as below:

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
```

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\f061";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  animation: spin-up 0.1s linear;
}

.caret-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Safari */
  '
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: spin-down 0.1s linear;
}


/*I've been added below CSS code*/

@keyframes spin-down {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
    transform: rotate(25deg);
  }
  50.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
    transform: rotate(40deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}


/*I've been added below CSS code*/

@keyframes spin-up {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
    transform: rotate(40deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
  }
  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
    transform: rotate(25deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  50.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span class="caret">Beverages</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Black Tea</li>
          <li>White Tea</li>
          <li><span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sencha</li>
              <li>Gyokuro</li>
              <li>Matcha</li>
              <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But unfortunately, I have unwanted extra animation, for seeing the problem, expand all nodes and collapse main node(`Beverages`) leave all other nodes expanded(`Tea`,`Green Tea`) when you expanded `Beverages` node again..!! you can see an extra and unwanted animation on `Tea` and `Green Tea`. This is my problem. How can I fix this out?

> See gif for clarification:
>   [image: showing extra animation]

Comment: Do you mean how the children don't return to collapsed because the parent was used to collapse? Not sure of the unwanted animation you're speaking of.

Comment: When you run the example and click on an expandable node, you have unwanted animation on children nodes, for example when you open the first node(`Beverages`) and look precisely the last node(`Tea`) you saw extra collapsing animation that is unwanted

Comment: In FF60 I can see that all the arrows get animated but not the extra collapsing animation. Maybe a browser related thing? Which browsers have you tested?

Comment: @David getting animated unclicked node is extra animation.I've been added gif for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this isn't the proper way of answering this question but an alternate way of doing this would be using a transition rather than a keyframe animation. It seems like you are doing alot more than necessary to just animate a 45 degree rotation.

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
```

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\f061";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition:all 0.1s linear;
}

.caret-down::before {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span class="caret">Beverages</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Black Tea</li>
          <li>White Tea</li>
          <li><span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sencha</li>
              <li>Gyokuro</li>
              <li>Matcha</li>
              <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the animation starts as soon as the element gets shown on the page. So you have to reset the animation property to the initial value when that happens. This css code disables the animation.

```
.active .caret.caret-down::before {
    animation: initial;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a complete answer, please?